# How to increase performance of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have an chat application written in jsp and jQuery. I have used the setTimeout method for threads who are continuously posting request in some URL. My browser is hanging after some time and cpu utilization is very high.

Is there any way to increase performance of JS?

Comment: I suspect your design.

Comment: Post some code please. I never had jQuery hang on me.

Comment: 99% of the time, the only way to increase performance of JS is to write better code.  I am guessing you do not fully understand the language and/or how it works.

Comment: I modified my answer check it out :)

Comment: for a good answer code will have to be posted.

Answer (score 1):

Check this one:
http://www.tvidesign.co.uk/blog/improve-your-jquery-25-excellent-tips.aspx#tip1

It has some really good recommendations like:

- Keep selection operations to a minimum by caching
- Keep DOM manipulation to a minimum
- Use IDs instead of classes wherever possible
- Give your selectors a context

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried debugging with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)?  You can use it to debug javascript, monitor requests and responses, and more.

Answer (score -2):

Well i run trough this before here is what i did (by the way this has nothing to do with jquery) :

```
try {
    window.clearInterval(x);
} catch(e) {
    // do nothing
}
x = setInterval(Update, 1000);
```

in your case you should clearTimeout :)

try this :

```
refresh() { $.post("./chatServlet",  {  message: "hxci",  name: $("#author").val(),  event: "AUTOROOMMESSAGE",   roomname: $("#select").val() },   function(xml)   {   $("#msg").empty();   addMessages(xml);    });    try {    window.clearInterval(x);}    catch(e) {       }     x = setInterval(refresh, 3000);   }
```

Comment: Since we are talking about optimization here, I should mention that there is no reason to check x for null before calling clearInterval.  That's just an additional cycle that we do not need!

Comment: Josh Stodola : The first time this will run the interval will be null and if you call window.clearInterval(x) and x is null ... 

and really do you think checking for null is a perf penalty ?

Comment: Why whould you clear the interval and set it new? Either you should always use `setTimeout()` or just let the interval run.

Comment: Well i had a recursive call to "update"     function Update() {
//magic here         
try {
            //window.clearInterval(x);
        }
        catch (e) {
            // do nothing
        }
        x = setInterval(Update, 1000);   
    }

the browser keeps taking more and more memory until it blocks the system but when i cleared the interval everything went back to normal !

Comment: hi Yassir

following is the my function
function refresh()
        {
            
            $.post("./chatServlet",
                {
                    message: "hxci",
                    name: $("#author").val(),
                    event: "AUTOROOMMESSAGE",
                    roomname: $("#select").val()
                }, function(xml) {
                $("#msg").empty();
                addMessages(xml);
            });
            setTimeout('refresh()',3000);
         }
i have 2 recursive func in my code like this.browser is taking high memory at client end.